# Set Netbeans Coffeescript Plugin Default Autocompile to On

Tags: netbeans, compilation, coffeescript, netbeans-plugins

I am using the [netbeans coffeescript plugin](http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/39007/coffeescript-netbeans).  The plugin has a feature to autocompile coffeescript to javascript and I use that feature frequently.  Unfortunately, the default functionality disables autocompile and requires me to manually select each file and turn on autocompiling as soon as I launch netbeans. As my project has grown, this process has become rather burdensome, requiring me to select 50+ files distributed over 10 or 15 different folders.  Is there a way to set the default autocompile behavior to `on` or is there a better way of going about this process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally came up with a workaround solution to this problem.

First, I run a project search for filenames matching `*.coffee`. This puts all of my coffeescript files from all of my subfolders into a single place. Then I can shift-click to select all files at once, and set to auto compile from `More>Coffeescript>Autocompile`